# SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT: Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version

Tags: php, linux, api, ssl, curl

I have access API with CURL working PHP 5.5.12 fine.but if reduce php version below 5.5 so i got error (**SSL_ERROR_PROTOCOL_VERSION_ALERT: Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version.**) so can you please suggest me. remove this error. and access API below php version 5.5.

Comment: My guess is: the curl version used by your php 5.5 package has suport for TSL1.1/1.2 while the older package does not.

Comment: We have resolved issue. with out update php version change below curl code curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); // 1, 2 or 3

Comment: We have already used. please add on curl both line. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: The error message is about the protocol (version), not the certificate verification.

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved issue. with out update php version change below curl code

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3); // 1, 2 or 3
```

We have already used. please add on curl both line.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

– Vinod Kumar Pal